# How to check a generic type's realtime type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
(<T extends number | string>({value}: Props<T>) => {

}
```

`T` is a generic type can be either `number` or `string`. Is there a way to check `T`'s type in realtime? Something like `typeof T === 'number'`? 
I know I can check the value type but I am looking for the generic type solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Typescript Design Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) list the following as one of it's non-goals

> Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system. Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.

I haven't personally used it but have heard of [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) library which might be worth checking out for the larger thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Since `T` is a simple primitive `typeof value === 'number'` should work just fine, don't think there is a need for io-ts

Comment: " I know I can check the value type but I am looking for the generic type solution." From the question, the asker says they know that already are looking for something else to deal with types. Hence the suggestion on io-ts.